# Objective-c : set attribute to property, does it preserve the default settings

Tags: objective-c

If I specify an attribute for a defined property, does it have any effect on the default attribute configuration?

For example, the following declarations are equal since `atomic, readwrite and strong` are set by default

```
@property(atomic,readwrite,strong)NSString *name;
@property NSString *name;
```

if I declare the property with `assign` attribute, does it keep the other attributes ?

are these 2 statements equivalent ?

```
@property (assign) NSString* name;
@property (assign,atomic,readwrite,strong) NSString * name;
```

and what happen if I change one default property, does it keep the other in their default setting ? are these 2 statements equivalent ?

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic,weak,readwrite) NSString * name;
```

I'm asking this since when I set a property with `assign` attribute only, it looks like the `strong` attribute is no longer applied, since when I set it with another variable, it doesn't retain reference.

Comment: `assign` and `strong` are mutually exclusive. `assign` says "don't retain" and `strong` says "retain". Is there a reason you're trying to use `assign`? (See "Setter Semantics" in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html for more info) The basic answer is "yes", though: if you don't specify an attribute, the default applies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various attributes of Objective-C properties are grouped into mutually exclusive sets of values. You can only pick one value from each group.

- A property is either atomic or nonatomic.
- A property is either readwrite or readonly.
- A property is either assign, weak, strong, or copy.
- A property is either nullable or nonnull.

So you can't make a property that is both `assign` and `strong`. It can only be one of them.

Picking a value from each group has no effect on the values in any other group.

For a reference type (`NSString *` for example), the defaults are atomic, readwrite, and strong as you have stated. Explicitly choosing a non-default value for one value does not change the other defaults.

You asked:

> are these 2 statements equivalent?

```
@property (assign) NSString* name;
@property (assign,atomic,readwrite,strong) NSString * name;
```

No since once you pick `assign`, `strong` is not used. On a side note, never use `assign` with a reference type unless you really, really have a good and fully understood reason to do so.

In other words, these are the same:

```
@property (assign) NSString *name;
@property (assign, atomic, readwrite) NSString *name;
```

Though again, don't use `assign` with reference types.

You asked if the following are equivalent:

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic,weak,readwrite) NSString * name;
```

Yes, these are the same. I use the 1st all of the time and the property is always readwrite as well.

---

I said you can only pick one value from each group. This is actually only partially true. In a class's public interface you can declare a property as readonly. And then in the class's private class extension, you can redeclare the property as readwrite. For example:

.h file:

```
@interface SomeClass

@property (readonly) NSString *someValue;

@end
```

.m file

```
@interface SomeClass ()

@property (readwrite) NSString *someValue;

@end
```

What this does is expose a readonly property to users of the class but allow the private implementation of the class to also write values to the property.